# How long is a .NET DateTime/TimeSpan tick?

Tags: .net, datetime, time, timespan

How long is a .NET DateTime/TimeSpan tick?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The [tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) is the unit of granularity for the .NET [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) value types.

It has the following common conversions:

```
1 tick = 100 nanoseconds
       = 0.1 microseconds
       = 0.0001 milliseconds
       = 0.0000001 seconds
```

Comment: You answered your own question one minute after posting it?

Comment: uh, StackOverflow encourages this sort of thing in the FAQ, dont down vote him for that.
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq#119658

Answer (score 79):

Although currently a tick is 100 nanoseconds, it is best not to rely on this as an absolute. Rather, use '`TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`' (or any of the other TicksPerXxx member values)

Comment: This is true. Don't hard code these in your code. However, they are absolute and will not be changed by Microsoft. The reason for this post is that sometimes one needs to do this math on a calculator and I wanted to make this chart available.

Comment: Example creating a 10 second timespan: `new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 10)`

Answer (score 13):

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx):

> The **smallest unit** of time is the tick, which is **equal to 100 nanoseconds**.

Metrology fail.

Answer (score 8):

Note that, although the theoretical resolution of DateTime.Now is quite high, the resolution - ie how often it is updated - it quite a bit lower.

Apparently, on modern systems, DateTime.Now has a resolution of 10 milliseconds... See [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)