# Stopwatch returning one tick

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch

I have a simple program that's supposed to sort a table, and measure the number of processor ticks needed to do it:

```
timePerRun = Stopwatch.StartNew();                                        
QuickSortLibrary.Quicksort.QuickSort(tabOfInts, 0, tabOfInts.Length-1);   
timePerRun.Stop();
```

The only problem is that when I'm trying to sort a table of ~15 elements, I get 1-4 ticks. Is it possible that it happens so quickly, or the stopwatch only measures what happens in this method, not in the one that does actual sorting?

Comment: that is measuring both. a table of 15 elements would be pretty quick to sort.

Comment: If you simply want to benchmark your program, just use something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org) and that's all.

Comment: It's not about benchmarking, It's supposed to measure it and display the value. I was just confused that it did the entire sorting so quickly

Comment: a modern cpu can do billions of operations per second. `Ticks` is not a measurement of CPU cycles.

Comment: is the `QuickSortLibrary.Quicksort.QuickSort` call happening on the same thread or a separate thread? Is it a optimized release build or a a debug build? Is the data well randomly generated for sorting or is contrived for a faster execution of `QuickSortLibrary.Quicksort.QuickSort`? On a single threaded, debug build, with random data scenario, I highly doubt the call finishes in a single tick. On the other hand, a release build with contrived data, it is possible (I would guess)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956483/how-long-is-a-net-datetime-timespan-tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really possible that this happens so quickly.  For so little elements, which all fit in the cache, it is a piece of joke for a contemporary CPU.